# Yeoman - multiple apps, shared dependencies

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to using Yeoman, and I'm working on a project that will have at least two apps - one for the front-end of a website, the other for an admin panel. It's in Backbone, but that part I think is irrelevant.
It's clear to me how to set up a single app using Yeoman. But how do you set up two, when both apps are sharing the same dependencies (ie. backbone, underscore, etc...).
Can't seem to find the answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two app folders - app1 and app2. The dependencies node_modules and bower_components will be at the root level. See below structure:

```
YourApp
  - node_modules
  - bower_components
  - app1
  - app2
  - bower.json
  - package.json
  - GruntFile.js
```

When you run grunt task to build your application. It basically looks for key `appPath` in `bower.json`. You can set this key value to the name of the folder you want to build. 
Another way would be to do some modification in `GruntFile.js` to have separate grunt tasks for building the different app folders. See Code below:

```
  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    app1: 'app1',  // Added new App1 here.. Similarly you can add multiple keys here.
    dist: 'dist'
  };
```

Added a new subtask livereload1 which will watch changes in app1 directory

```
  livereload1: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app1) // your new appConfig path
            ];
          }
        }
      }
```

Register a new Task `app1` to build `app1` folder

```
 grunt.registerTask('app1', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'wiredep',
          'concurrent:server',
          'autoprefixer:server',
          'connect:livereload1',
          'watch'
        ]);
      });
```

Similarly you can create new tasks for Test or Dist etc.